# MaxMind Geolite2-City doesn't show city and region information

Tags: maxmind

I am using **Geolite2-City** Database for Geolocation. In some cases not possible to get city, region except the country. For the IP - 205.145.64.6, the database provides the below details only (city, region details are missing).

[image]

Which Maxmind database have to use to get all the information including city, region details?

Answer (score 0):

Not all IP addresses will resolve to city level. In this case, there is no city information for 205.145.64.6

Comment: Hi Michael, The other tool resolves and shows the details for the same ip address - https://www.ip2location.com/205.145.64.6

Comment: Hi Ramesh, different provider has different accuracy.